# Is modeling the extreme value of a distribution a basic probability result?

Tags: probability, estimation, extreme-value, order-statistics

I was reading briefly about the field of EVT - extreme value theory, and the associated distributions that arise from modeling the maximum of a finite sample. It's not quite clear to me the nature of data and estimation that this field treats. Does it concern deriving the exact distribution of a maximum (or minimum), and/or does it concern analyzing samples that are maxima or minima from unobserved processes?

The practical need for this field is crystal clear. What I don't understand is why this should be considered a theoretically distinct field. On one hand, if the density of a distribution is known, one can trivially derive the density of a maximum or minimum. On the other, if one observes the extreme value of a sequence of independent process (like maximum daily rainfall over consecutive years in the Texas flats), intuitively, one would again use basic probability laws to identify a method for estimating the density function of a single observation, and again derive the density for an extreme for a given sample of size $n$.

Basically, I don't see an application of EVT that doesn't require an estimate or assumption regarding the density of the whole sample. Have I missed a scenario that should be considered?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Fisher-Tippett-Gnedenko Theorem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem)

Comment: @whuber It's the most famous result in this area, and a very interesting (statistical? probability?) result. This is precisely my confusion; if $f$ is unknown how are $a_n, b_n$ chosen, and how is the limiting asymptotic DF prized from among the 3 options? If $f$ *is* known, why would an asymptotic result be preferred when you can easily derive the DF of the order statistic directly?

Comment: The theorem and its relatives give criteria for determining which limiting distribution, if any, applies.  Although this theorem is similar to the CLT, unlike the CLT there is not a universal way to standardize the extrema.  Nevertheless, the result is asymptotically determined up to location and scale.  Thus, anyone looking at extreme phenomena has an excellent basis for choosing a parametric family for fitting, estimation, prediction, *etc.*  That's why study of this theorem is worthwhile.